# Filtering option in table.query function in python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, cx-oracle

I am using cx_oracle lib to fetch some data from Oracle DB and start performing some calculations.
Here in my code, I created a table and I want to plot my data in Subplots for each item in a column.

In my program, I used for loop and query from pandas lib to filter data based on a column value called "Sub", may you please help me to find out how I should write my code :

```
for i in list(Sub):
    temp=table.query('Subrack==["%s"]',i)
```

Sub is an numpy.ndarray with `['0' '1' '2']` values.

I want to filter Subrack column in my table using Sub values, but I am facing below error :

```
ValueError: For argument "inplace" expected type bool, received type str.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
table.query('Subrack == [{}]'.format(i))
```

I am not so sure about `[]`,depending on how the content of the column it's not necessary and you can just write `Subrack == {}`.

The error arises because you provide i to the method query, which assumes you provide the *inplace* argument. See pandas documentation:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html